# Adding <select> inside of <td>

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have this code that creates a table with 7 columns.

The table returns like this:
[1][2][3][4][5][6][7] << headers
[1][2][3][4][5][6][7] << values

Where the 7th column is an `<a>` button inside of a `<td>`.

I'm trying to figure out how to add a `<select>` with `<option>'s` inside of the 6th columns `<td>`.

```
  //create table
  var artistFileValues = artistFile.getDataRange().getValues();
  var isHeader = true;
  var table = "<table id='table-noValues'>\n";
  var caption = "<caption>" + name + "</caption>\n";

  table += caption;

  for (var i = 0; i < artistFileValues.length; i++)
  {
    table += "<tr>\n";

    for (var j = 0; j < artistFileValues[i].length; j++)
    {
      if (isHeader)
      {
        table += "<th>" + artistFileValues[i][j] + "</th>\n"; //headers
        if (j == artistFileValues[i].length - 1) //if last header in row, add another cell with 'add' button
        {
          table += "<th style='text-align: center;'>" + "<a id='addButton' onclick=\x22addRow(this)\x22>" + "&plus;" + "</a>" + "</th>\n"; //'+' button
        }
      }
      else
      {
        table += "<td contenteditable='false'>" + artistFileValues[i][j] + "</td>\n"; //values
        if (j == artistFileValues[i].length - 1) //if last data in row, add another cell with 'delete' button
        {
          table += "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + "<a id='deleteButton' onclick=\x22deleteRow(this)\x22>" + "&times;" + "</a>" + "</td>\n"; //'x' button
        }
      }
    }
    isHeader = false;
    table += "</tr>\n";
  }
  table += "</table>";
  table += "<button id='calculateButton' onclick='calculate()'>" + "Calculate" + "</button>"; //add calculate button to bottom of table
  return table;
```

I'm assuming I'd have to implement an if statement or a for loop that counts to 5 and then adds the  inside of the 6th . I'm not really sure what the best way to do this is, or if this is even the right way to do it.

But any help would be appreciated.

Comment: to be on-topic first show us your attempts and what is failing.

Comment: I would used templated HTML for this.  What I do is have two HTML files, one for the mostly fixed HTML, and then one for the template of each row.  It gets complicated, but my point is:  for HTML that isn't going to change, just have an HTML file with the basic structure, and then the parts that are going to change, have a "scriptlet."  Either way, it's going to get complicated and difficult to debug.  To some degree you are asking a debugging question.  Concatenating text is great.  I use it all the time, but I also like to have template text with merge fields that I replace.

Comment: For example:  `var myOptionTemplate = "<option my_Merge_field_for_Value>merge_field_for_displayed_text</option>"`  Then use `replace()` to replace the values:  `var optionHtml = myOptionTemplate.replace("my_Merge_field_for_Value",thisRowValue)`

Comment: @SandyGood I have the other html files. The table returns fine, it's just making the <select> inside of the <td> for the 6th column that I'm having trouble with. I don't understand the my_merge_field_for_value  and _displayed_text you're showing. Like for the first line of the else statement, it makes all 6 columns a <td>, but how would I change that to make only 5 columns <td> and then the 6th a <td><select><option></option><option></option><option></option></select></td>?

Answer (score 0):

Just figure out where you want to put it and given the below function your optionscsv string and valuescsv string and it will generate all of the tags for the select and options opening and closing  tags.

```
function mySelect(optionscsv,valuescsv)
{
  var optionscsv = (typeof(optionscsv) !== 'undefined')?optionscsv : null;
  var valuescsv = (typeof(valuescsv) !== 'undefined')?valuescsv : null;
  var s='<select>';
  if(valuescsv && optionscsv)
  {
    var optionsA = optionscsv.split(',');
    var valuesA = valuescsv.split(',');
    if(optionsA.length == valuesA.length)
    {
      for(var i = 0; i < optionsA.length; i++)
      {
        s += '<option value="' + valuesA[i] + '">' + optionsA[i] + '</option>';
      }
      s += '</select>';
    }
    else
    {
      s ='';
    }
    
  }
  else
  {
    s = '';
  }
  return s;
}
```

And below I took a guess at where you might wish to put it and how you could do it:

```
for (var j = 0; j < artistFileValues[i].length; j++)
    {
      if (isHeader)
      {
        table += "<th>" + artistFileValues[i][j] + "</th>\n"; //headers
        if (j == artistFileValues[i].length - 1) //if last header in row, add another cell with 'add' button
        {
          table += "<th style='text-align: center;'>" + "<a id='addButton' onclick=\x22addRow(this)\x22>" + "&plus;" + "</a>" + "</th>\n"; //'+' button
        }
      }
      else
      {
        if(j!==5)//I'm guessing this is the sixth column
        {
            table += "<td contenteditable='false'>" + artistFileValues[i][j] + "</td>\n"; //values
        }
        else
        {
            var s = mySelect(optionscsv,valuescsv);
            table += "<td contenteditable='false'>" + artistFileValues[i][j] + s + "</td>\n"; //values
        }
        if (j == artistFileValues[i].length - 1) //if last data in row, add another cell with 'delete' button
        {
          table += "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + "<a id='deleteButton' onclick=\x22deleteRow(this)\x22>" + "&times;" + "</a>" + "</td>\n"; //'x' button
        }
      }
    }
```